# Node.js server Browser rendering html file as text - All content types correct

Tags: html, node.js, server

I am using a node.js file to start a server but my browser just renders the html as text.

- The html file has the .html extension.
- I have added all the necessary
  Content-Type headers

At my whits end any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**File Structure**

```
03_Feeds-Speed        
├─ scripts            
│  ├─ FeedsSpeeds.js  
│  ├─ main.js         
│  └─ Page.js         
├─ styles             
│  └─ style.css       
├─ index.html         
├─ README.md          
└─ server.js
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Feeds & Speeds</title>
  <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="nav" class="navbar">
    <nav>
      <h2>Navigation</h2>
      <div id="FeedSpeed_button">
        <p>Feeds & Speeds</p>
      <div id="Material_button">
        <p>Materials</p>
        <P>Tool Library</P>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="content">
    <input type="button" id="but" value="click me">
  </div>

  <script type="module" src="scripts/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
let http = require('http');
let fs = require('fs');



http.createServer(function (req, res){
    fs.readFile('index.html', 'utf-8', function (err, data) {

        if (err){
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.write("problem!")
        } else {

            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type' : 'text/html',
                'Content-Type' : 'text/css',
                'Content-Type' : 'application/javascript'
            }, charset='UTF-8');

        res.write(data);
        return res.end();

        }});
}).listen(7800);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are sending inappropriate headers and you are not sending css and js files so you won't see a response.
Here is a fix to your problem.
server.js should be like this.

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const loadAndStream = (filePath, mineType, res) => {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, "UTF-8");
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": mineType});
    fileStream.pipe(res);
}



http.createServer(function (req, res){
    if(req.url === '/'){
        const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html');
        loadAndStream(filePath, 'text/html', res)
    }
    if(req.url === '/styles/style.css'){
        const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'styles', 'style.css');
        loadAndStream(filePath, 'text/css', res);
    }
    if(req.url === '/scripts/main.js'){
        const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'scripts', 'main.js');
        loadAndStream(filePath, 'application/json', res)
    }
}).listen(7800);
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this, it makes sense i always thought the request was in the html file. I folded and used express but Do I need to worry about the css files being static here too? Thanks

Comment: Yes the request is sent but you should handle it in node, that why I added the last two conditions. If you are going to use express then you also need to serve static assets, you should add a middleware like this: create a public folder and then add this line before route handlers app.use(express.static(__dirname, 'public')) and then put the css and js folders inside the public folder. here app is express()